# Jquery fadeIn image

Tags: jquery

I have few images and when one of them is pressed i want the other ones to fade out.

```
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <img class="images" id="img" src="/images/user1.png" height="100" width="100">
    <img class="images" id="img2" src="/images/user2.png" height="100" width="100">
    <img class="images" id="img3" src="/images/user3.png" height="100" width="100"><br>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#img').mouseover(function () {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            });
            $('#img2').mouseover(function () {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            });
            $('#img3').mouseover(function () {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.images', function (event) {
            $(event.target.id).fadeIn(1000);
            $(".images:not(#" + event.target.id + ")").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);

        });


    </script>


</body>
```

the problem is that when i press on a different image from the first i pressed all the images stay fadeout. it looks like the fadein i added for the pressed image doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the one you are clicking on to `fadeTo("fast",1)`

```
$(document).on('click', '.images', function (event) {
    $(".images:not(#" + event.target.id + ")").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1); // This is the new line
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2w4vS/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

1. "$(event.target.id)" is not a valid selector. You could write
   "$('#' + event.target.id)" but "$(event.target)" is much easier.
2. The jQuery "fadeIn" function will only fade from opacity:0 to
   opacity:1, not to or from any other value.

What you end up with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function(event) {
        $(event.target).fadeTo(500, 1.0);
        $('img').not(event.target).fadeTo(500, 0.5);
    });
});
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WFy2/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend scrapping your code and doing this:

**CSS**

```
.images {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.images', function () {
    $('.images').not(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    $(this).fadeTo(1000,1);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u2kGJ/)**

Answer (score 0):

i think closer answer to your question is:

```
 $("#"+event.target.id).fadeTo("fast" , 1);
 $(".images:not(#" + event.target.id + ")").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
```